# how to get rid of TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined error?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to get `id`, `first` and `last name` of users using `createListItems()` inside `user-list.js` file.

But, I got

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

error when I ran the program, and `(line7 / user-list.js) return this.props.users.map(user => {` is red (not working).

I do not know why I get this error, and how to fix it.
Does anyone know how to get rid of this error?

user-list.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class UserList extends Component {
  createListItems() {
    return this.props.users.map(user => {
      return (
        <li key={user.id}>
          {user.first}
          {user.last}
        </li>
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <ul>{this.createListItems()}</ul>;
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    users: state.users
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(UserList);
```

index.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import UserList from "../containers/user-list";

class Index extends Component {
  state = {};
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>username list:</h2>
        <UserList />
        <hr />
        <h2>user details:</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Index;
```

Comment: You haven't passed a list to the users props inside index.js

Comment: At least do this:
`const { users = [] } = this.props` on the first line of the UserList class. And replace `this.props.users.map` with `users.map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As warkentien2 mentioned, you're not passing the users array to the `<UserList />` component. You need to create an array in index.js of your users (manually or pulled from somewhere else) and pass it off like this: `<UserList users={[{id: 1, first: "John", last: "Doe"}]} />`

Comment: Then what is the use of redux?

Answer (score 0):

When `UserList` mounts, it takes initial state. And initially `users` state might be `null` / `empty`.

You need to check if data is present,

```
<ul>{ this.props.users && this.props.users.length > 0 && this.createListItems() }</ul>;
```